# How to extract files from multiple zip folder

Tags: windows

I am trying to extract multiple sub folders with different name from one mail folder e.g MainFolder(Main) and Subfloders Folder1.zip , Datafolder.zip.

Please assist

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried so far and at what point you run into trouble.

Comment: Oh, your question isn't clarify.